# Finding matching lines with gawk and regexp

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a a file that contains lines like these:

```
(+0.010605625808,-0.187753006816)|000000000100> +
(-0.090206444263,+0.071405023336)|000000000101> +
(-0.090206436813,+0.071404993534)|000000000110> +
(+0.069306485355,+0.012268572114)|000000000111> +
(+0.010605554096,-0.187753051519)|000000001000> +
(-0.104045681655,+0.102472946048)|000000001001> +
```

I need to take the unsiged value of the two numbered columns:
`0.010605625808` and `0.187753006816` for instance.

This is the awk line that I expect to work

```
awk '$0 ~ /^\((.*),/ {print $1 "and" $2}' examples.txt
```

But this is the output:

```
(+0.217999786139,+0.216710388660)|000000000000>and+
(+0.010605582036,-0.187753096223)|000000000001>and+
(+0.010605548508,-0.187753096223)|000000000010>and+
(-0.090206362307,+0.071405015886)|000000000011>and+
(+0.010605625808,-0.187753006816)|000000000100>and+
(-0.090206444263,+0.071405023336)|000000000101>and+
(-0.090206436813,+0.071404993534)|000000000110>and+
(+0.069306485355,+0.012268572114)|000000000111>and+
(+0.010605554096,-0.187753051519)|000000001000>and+
(-0.104045681655,+0.102472946048)|000000001001>and+
```

Is my problem with regexps or awk? 
Thanks.

Comment: please edit your Q to show at the required output given your sample input. One thing you can fix is `" and "` (extra spaces, assuming your want that). Good luck.

Comment: What does `I need to take` mean? Print? Delete? Add? Something else? [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify little bit

```
$ awk -F'[(,)]' '{gsub(/[-+]/,""); print $2,$3}' file

0.010605625808 0.187753006816
0.090206444263 0.071405023336
0.090206436813 0.071404993534
0.069306485355 0.012268572114
0.010605554096 0.187753051519
0.104045681655 0.102472946048
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[(),+-]' '{print $3,$5}' file
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.